# And-ing , OR-ing for Sets in python

Tags: python

So I have

```
a=set(["a"])
b=set(["b"])
```

`c=a&b` would return a empty set, `c=set([])`
But when i type `c = a and b`, why does it give me a `set(["b"])`

What is the "`and`" and "`or`" doing when used in two sets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things.

1. I'd recommend using set literal syntax if you're on Python 2.7 or above. You can just do `a = {"a"}`.
2. The keywords `and` and `or` are logical operators. They're used for Python's conditional logic. The `|` and `&` operators are bitwise; they are overloaded by the `set()` class. What you should be doing is `a & b`. You can read more here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

If you try `a = 5 and 6` you will see the result is `6`. That is how boolean operators work in many programming languages, including Python. It's essentially saying "check if the value on the left evaluates to `True`, if so, return the value on the right."

Answer (score 0):

The answers here regarding `or` and `and` are a little wanting here.  It's true that they're boolean operators and have nothing to do with sets, though.  They're short-circuit boolean operators and are fairly commonly used as a short cut for assigning values with fallback values.

Here's how it works...

If you have a statement saying `a or b` and you had to evaluate if that whole statement was true, you'd first start by figuring out if `a` was true.  If you found `a` *was* true, then you don't need to bother evaluating `b` because true or'ed with anything is always true.  On the other hand, if `a` is false, you have to evaluate `b` to determine if the whole statement is false or not.  Also, whatever `b` is will be the result of the whole `a or b` statement.

So, `x = a or b` will first test if `a` is true and if it is the whole right side of the statement will become `a`.  Likewise, if `a` is false, the whole right side becomes `b` because `b` will determine if `a or b` is true since we know `a` is false.

`and` is also a short circuit operator.  With `a and b`, if `a` is false we can stop evaluating and say the whole statement is false and ignore `b`.  If `a` is true, the whole statement relies on the boolean value of `b`.

So, `x = a and b` will first test if `a` is true.  If `a` is true, then the result of `a and b` can be simplified to `b` and then the statement becomes `x = b`.  If `a` is false, then we can stop at `a` and just replace `a and b` with `a` making it `x = a`.

I don't think I've ever seen the use of `and` in this fashion, but it does work.

Answer (score -1):

`a and b` is returning `b`. This is boolean logic, not a set intersection. In Python, the following are "falsy" objects: `None`, `False`, `0`, `""`, `[]`, `tuple()`, `set([])`, etc. Since `a` and `b` are both "truthy" objects, `b` is returned from `a and b`.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions

One use of this is to initialize a variable like this:

```
def f(x):
    x = x or MyObject()
```

Answer (score -2):

`c=a&b` returns the intersection of the two sets, which in this case is nothing. `c=a and b` uses the standard Python logical operators. So when you say `c=a and b` you are basically saying c=(a is True) and (b is True). Naively, since both a and b in this case are not empty and evaluate to True, you would expect c to be True. However, when you use the logical operators to set a value, Python returns not just True but the value of the last True object, which in this case is b.